# MySQL Installation Configuation unable to proceed

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, installation

I am trying to set up a mysql server environment on windows. I have downloaded mysql community server installation file for windows. There was no problem for installation,  but when I proceeded to configuration of mysql server, I cannot proceed anymore.

[image]

According to the instruction online, mysql installer should have buttons like "next" and "cancel" etc. However there is nowhere for me to click and if I close the window I would exit the installer. Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the installer when your Windows font size is set to 125%.

Find the display settings in control panel and try setting your font size back to 100% and see if the button is then appearing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much life saver!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to upvote my answer ;-)